# Evento keyup não deve ativar com teclas especiais

Tags: jquery, keyup

Em meu `document` estou criando alguns atalhos no teclado para facilitar o uso da página em si, e estou a fazê-lo da seguinte forma:

```
$(document).on("keyup", function(e){
    /*Tecla C*/
    if(e.which === 67){
       alert("A tecla C foi pressionada");
    }
});
```

Acima quando a C for pressionada a página deve executar uma ação, mas como lidar com as teclas especiais, pois da forma que está se o usuário pressionar `CTRL + C`, o evento será ativado, como eu posso impedir que isso acontece com este atalho e com os vários outros padrões do teclado? Se possível eu não gostaria de ter que desativar tais eventos padrões do teclado / sistema operacional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se entendi bem o que tu quer, uma alternativa seria só chamar determinado evento se a tecla <kbd>C</kbd> for acionada sem nenhuma combinação, em outras palavras, o evento só é acionado se clicar somente na tecla <kbd>C</kbd>

```js
var keys = [];

$(document).keydown(function (e) {
    keys.push(e.which);
});

$(document).on("keyup", function(e){
    /*Tecla C*/
    if(e.which === 67 && keys.length == 1){
       alert("A tecla C foi pressionada");
       //...evento...
    }
    keys = []
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Perfeito, é exatamente o que eu preciso <3

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar as propriedades:

- metaKey para identificar se a tecla Windows ou Command (OSX) foi pressionada.
- altKey para identificar se a tecla alt esta pressionada
- ctrlKey para identificar se a tecla control esta pressionada

Criei um [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f9bcee69/) de exemplo com o trecho abaixo:

```
  $('#teste').on("keyup", function(event){

    if(event.metaKey) {
        $("#status").html("Metakey pressionada");
    }

    if(event.altKey) {
        $("#status").html("Tecla alt pressionada");
    }

    if(event.ctrlKey) {
        $("#status").html("Tecla control pressionada");
    }

  });
```